# Error: Cannot find module 'symbol-observable' in Angular

Tags: npm, angular-cli

I'm getting the below error while running *ng new*. Tried with cmd opening as Administrator, but not helping.

```
D:\Training\Angular>ng new test
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:797
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'symbol-observable'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\mubarakm\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\lib\init.js
- C:\Users\mubarakm\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng
←[90m    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:794:15)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:687:27)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:849:19)←[39m
←[90m    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)←[39m
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\mubarakm\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\←[4m@angular←[24m\cli\lib\init.js:10:1)
←[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:30)←[39m
←[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:849:19)←[39m {
  code: ←[32m'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'←[39m,
  requireStack: [
    ←[32m'C:\\Users\\mubarakm\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\@angular\\cli\\lib\\init.js'←[39m,
    ←[32m'C:\\Users\\mubarakm\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\@angular\\cli\\bin\\ng'←[39m
  ]
}
```

Comment: maybe it's a bad installation of angular cli, try to reinstall it
* npm cache verify 
* npm install -g @angular/cli

Comment: I tried it, but this error is coming up again frequently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `npm i --save symbol-observable` (or `Yarn`, then, `Yarn add symbol-observable`)
2. `npm install` (or `Yarn`)
3. `npm outdated` (or `yarn outdated`) to check for outdated dependencies(symbol-observable) then upgrading it to the corresonding version if needed by entering `yarn upgrade symbol-observable @[version]`

Else,
check if you import it correctly from

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
```

to

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
```

otherwise,you may have Rxjs issues as mentionned here https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4756

Comment: Will try. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Simply check for any outdated dependencies using `"npm outdated"`, and if there are any update the angular cli using command "npm update -g @angular/cli", should be good to go.